# Cipher with random alphanumeric characters. What kind of cipher is this?

Tags: cipher

My friend sent me a cipher with 3 parts (without telling me how to separate the parts. He encrypted each part in a different way, then the whole thing was encrypted again. He says that part 2 is longer than part 3, which in turn is longer than part 1, so 2>3>1. It is in base 10 and it doesn't make sense in any other bases anyway. It should mostly be in English but the last part is a poem, perhaps in German. Weirdly, he also provided this poem from *Ready Player One* by Ernest Cline:

> "Three hidden keys open three secret gates
> Wherein the errant will be tested for worthy traits
> And those with the skill to survive these straits
> Will reach The End where the prize awaits"
> -Ernest Cline, Ready Player One

I don't know how to solve it because the text has seemingly random jumbles of alphanumeric characters. Here it is:

```
W3CWLI186N66NE6G9E6E76LLA31R7WRH5F1A7WR3WTETDO3B36T6RA3606RR6O6I9V86NW6F7W1A1FOH9TADUVIDUOIV7VME66DWE6AMWSSODDPSUBHADU2EAIE8WLDV7BWPVIEVMWVIW9WD9SW7LDYPWYVDJDY2E2DYW9WYJWBVUL7DLW6VERS76I5U6V7BW7L6UYWPD2W6V7BVYELCU7S7VA9YD2DVWBD22DLPWJWLBWELP6WBUYWBD22DL9YD69WY7VAJDYVIW6EHWDJDUYJUVUYW6ELPJDYW8WY67OLWPOWDYOWME6I7LOVDLONIRFWAN6W12NAGFRCTOTOPAN6S1A156OU6GU6G2FFPH3SLAN6RW6OSNW6DFH3A1FOTOPTHHANTAAN6W61GOFG3SNW1PPH6H1L6LWUBAFGTAAN6S1TGFUF3PFOAFTD6AF4N3WO6UAFAN66OPPFRAN6IFWHPFW2FPRFWX1PAN63GTAFR1OPGNC6AN1O21RUF3I6OAAN1GRTWTOPTW6G661O2AN1GC6GGT26AN6OSFO2WTA3HTA1FOGUF3NTD6GFHD6PAN6XW6OB13GS1BN66G12O6PX66OB13G
```

I managed to find some patterns in  letter location, such as V only appearing in the first half, X only appearing at the end, Y only appearing in the middle, no Z in the entire text etc. I believe this may be some sort of computer encryption, yet I cannot think of any method in base 10 that could have random alphanumeric characters. What kind of cipher is this, and how can I solve it?

The poem is probably not that related. I'm not quite sure what kind of cipher was used, but I believe it is similar to something that already exists. I believe my friend used some sort of cipher similar to computer encryption, but still human-solvable (possibly with the help of online tools, but not requiring an actual program to be written)

Answer (score 7):

### Plaintext

> Split the ciphertext into three parts:

> ```
> W3CWLI186N66NE6G9E6E76LLA31R7WRH5F1A7WR3WTETDO3B36T6RA3606RR
> 6O6I9V86NW6F7W1A1FOH9T
>
> ADUVIDUOIV7VME66DWE6AMWSSODDPSUBHADU2EAIE8WLDV7BWPVIEVMWVIW9
> WD9SW7LDYPWYVDJDY2E2DYW9WYJWBVUL7DLW6VERS76I5U6V7BW7L6UYWPD2
> W6V7BVYELCU7S7VA9YD2DVWBD22DLPWJWLBWELP6WBUYWBD22DL9YD69WY7V
> AJDYVIW6EHWDJDUYJUVUYW6ELPJDYW8WY67OLWPOWDYOWME6I7LOVDL
>
> ONIRFWAN6W12NAGFRCTOTOPAN6S1A156OU6GU6G2FFPH3SLAN6RW6OSNW6DF
> H3A1FOTOPTHHANTAAN6W61GOFG3SNW1PPH6H1L6LWUBAFGTAAN6S1TGFUF3P
> FOAFTD6AF4N3WO6UAFAN66OPPFRAN6IFWHPFW2FPRFWX1PAN63GTAFR1OPGN
> C6AN1O21RUF3I6OAAN1GRTWTOPTW6G661O2AN1GC6GGT26AN6OSFO2WTA3HT
> A1FOGUF3NTD6GFHD6PAN6XW6OB13GS1BN66G12O6PX66OB13G
> ```

> Solve each part as a simple substitution. I could not find a method to the substitution that explains all of the apparent enciphering mistakes: a nonsense word at the beginning, occasional cases of a plaintext letter having two cipher equivalents, and cases of a cipher letter having two plain equivalents. It seems to be calling itself the "Brenpius Cipher", could that be your friend's name?

> ```
> W3CWLI186N66NE6G9E6E76LLA31R7WRH5F1A7WR3WTETDO3B36T6RA3606RR
> ah?alyivebeebdecodedwellthiswasfunitwashardrightheresthemess
>
> 6O6I9V86NW6F7W1A1FOH9T
> egeyouvebaenwaitingfor
>
>
> ADUVIDUOIV7VME66DWE6AMWSSODDPSUBHADU2EAIE8WLDV7BWPVIEVMWVIW9
> youthoughtitwassoeasywellgoodluckyoumayhavenoticedthatwethep
>
> WD9SW7LDYPWYVDJDY2E2DYW9WYJWBVUL7DLW6VERS76I5U6V7BW7L6UYWPD2
> eopleinordertoformamoreperfectunionestablishjusticeinsuredom
>
> W6V7BVYELCU7S7VA9YD2DVWBD22DLPWJWLBWELP6WBUYWBD22DL9YD69WY7V
> estictranquilitypromotecommondefenceandsecurecommonprosperit
>
> AJDYVIW6EHWDJDUYJUVUYW6ELPJDYW8WY67OLWPOWDYOWME6I7LOVDL
> yforthesakeofourfuturesandforeversignedgeorgewashington
>
>
> ONIRFWAN6W12NAGFRCTOTOPAN6S1A156OU6GU6G2FFPH3SLAN6RW6OSNW6DF
> nhwfortherightsofmanandthecitizenyesyesgoodluckthefrenchrevo
>
> H3A1FOTOPTHHANTAAN6W61GOFG3SNW1PPH6H1L6LWUBAFGTAAN6S1TGFUF3P
> lutionandallthatthereisnosuchriddlelikekryptosattheciasoyoud
>
> FOAFTD6AF4N3WO6UAFAN66OPPFRAN6IFWHPFW2FPRFWX1PAN63GTAFR1OPGN
> ontoavetojhurneytotheenddoftheworldorgodforbidtheusatofindsh
>
> C6AN1O21RUF3I6OAAN1GRTWTOPTW6G661O2AN1GC6GGT26AN6OSFO2WTA3HT
> methingifyouwentthisfarandareseeingthismessagethencongratula
>
> A1FOGUF3NTD6GFHD6PAN6XW6OB13GS1BN66G12O6PX66OB13G
> tionsyouhavesolvedthebrenpiuscipheesignedbeenpius
> ```

> ```
> Here are the substitution keys, as best as I can figure:
>
> Plain:     abcdefghiijklmnopqrsttuuvwxyz
> Cipher 1:  WNGE6HO31D..L0F9..TRAB5V87.I.
> Cipher 2:  ERBPWJOI7.5HS2LD9CY6V.U.8M.A.
> Cipher 3:  TXSP6R2N1.4LHCOFB.WGA.3.DI.U5
> ```

### Solve path

> I put the entire cipher into AZDecrypt, a robust program for solving substitution ciphers. It gave me a hundred nonsense words, but near the end I saw phrases `SEEING THIS YESSAGE THEN CONGRATULATIONS` and `THE FRENCH RESOLUTION AND ALL THAT`. These cribs allowed me to complete the solution by hand and identify where each of the three different substitutions began and ended.